# Weaker notion of normality

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

Let $A$ be a square matrix with real entries. The matrix $A$ is called *normal* if $A^TA=AA^T$. The matrices $A^TA$ and $AA^T$ are both symmetric and have the same eigenvalues. Using the Spectral Theorem, we can show that there exists an orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that $Q^{T}(A^TA)Q=AA^T$ holds, that is, $AQ$ is normal.

Hence, for any real square matrix $A$, there exists an orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that the matrix $AQ$ is normal.

I wish to study matrices $A$ for which $P^T(A^TA)P=AA^T$ holds for some permutation matrix $P$. This is equivalent to the matrix $AP$ being normal. Perhaps, such matrices can be called weak normal matrices?

Has such matrices or this notion been studied before? Could you share some references? I'm also interested in the case when the entries of $A$ are either $0$ or $1$.